# flash a firmware of HTC device with different main version? FIX HTC corrupt - relocked - s-on

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, htc, ruu

I have an HTC U11 Life, bricked, CID 332, Telcel operator, main version 2.16.600.1, and S-On. Unfortunately, there is no firmware with this build.

I found firmware for this phone, but the only problem is the main version is different.

How can I flash the phone with a different main version? Or even unlock the bootloader without enabling OEM unlock because the phone won't fully turn on?

Answer (score 0):

I searched on the internet for months and nothing because there is no RUU or firmware for my phone's main version. Finally, I found a way by myself:

1. Decrypt the RUU file with "HTC RUU decrypt" software. When the program asks you to keep firmware files, press yes. Or use "HTC OTA downloader" software for downloading OTA ZIP files and extracting IMG files for flashing. Note that your file should have the same CID. If you modified your CID, it might work.
2. You should disassemble the phone, remove eMMC, and put it on the Jtag interface of the UFI box. If you are not an expert, go to a repair shop and ask them to do it.
3. When the UFI box recognizes the eMMC and shows you some info, skip it and go to the "Userarea partitions" section. From the "Special tasks" menu, choose factory reset and wait for the operation to finish.

   After that, look at the partition list. Next to each partition, there is a text that says "click for load image". Click on each partition that you want. Necessary partitions are "system", "boot", and "recovery". If you want, you can backup them from your eMMC.

   Load those partitions (*do not touch other partitions, you may damage your network*). After the images are loaded, just check the checkbox and press the write button.
   After that, from the "Special tasks" menu, choose factory reset again.
4. Put the eMMC back on the phone and boot normally, the job is done!